# What is "Hello, world!" for ReactJS Native Apple Watch WatchKit apps and Glances?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, reactjs-native

As best I can tell for now, React Native for iOS offers tooling to talk to an iPhone or iPad, but I've looked and failed to find documentation for how to talk to an Apple Watch, via WatchKit or glances.

Is there a "Hello, world?" available demonstrating both Watchkit and Glances in ReactJS Native, filling out `awakeWithContext()` and `willActivate()` with a single static image sized to the watch viewport size?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't support for WatchKit, yet.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/685